# sending post or get information in jquery autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-plugins

Hello we are using the jquery autocomplete function but want to extract information from a php script which is not only dependent upon what is inside the text box.  The text box is a contact name coming from a contacts table.  Our problem is that we want to pull only those contacts that are associated to a certain company.  This company's id will also be in the contacts table so the query will look like this in the script

```
  $query = "SELECT * 
                  FROM u_contact
                  WHERE full_name like '" . $_GET['term'] . "%' 
                  AND entity_id = '$_GET[ent]'";
```

where $_Get[ent] would be the id of the company.  Ive been looking on jquery website for how to do this without any help. How do I send this get information using just the jquery autocomplete function?

Comment: I'll be the first (and surely not the last) to say that you should NEVER insert $_GET[anything] in your SQL queries. You need to sanitize your input first or you have a major injection vulnerability.

Comment: For example I could just go to hxxp://yourdomain.com/yourscript.php?term=%27%3BDROP%20TABLE%20u_contact ... and there goes your contacts table.

Comment: Where is the company ID coming from? Can you post the HTML and Javascript that you're using?

Comment: just a suggestion: with autocomplete tools it is better to cache result otherwise it will trigger a query foreach keypress. Just get all your data and then filter them with php. As ithcy asked: show us some html

Comment: I could just do a is_numeric to stop that.  You didn't answer my question . How would I send post or get data within the function. Is  it the same way you do it with the $.ajax function or is that functionality on the auto-complete not accessible.  My HTML is just an input tag that has the auto-complete function associated to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post the data using the `$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );` like statements so that you can pass ent and the term at a time and get back the results.

Refer : `http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/`